# how to toggle between languages in java web

Tags: java, struts, multilingual

I am using struts, I have a java web application which needs to run on two languages. I am able to get one language using application.properties file where I have key and values combination and use it. Now when the user wants to select select some other language than how to switch to another language `how to change the properties file`

I have different properties file for different language my problem is how to set/select the particular properties file when user selects different language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Struts2 then you can create your own `LocaleProvider` class, something like:

```
public class ChangeLocale implements LocaleProvider {  

        private String lan;  

        public String getLan() {  
            return lan;  
        }  
        public void setLan(String lan) {  
            this.lan = lan;  
        }  
        public Locale getLocale() {  

            Locale locale=null;
            // Switch language between Chinese and English  
            if("chinese".equals(lan)){  
                locale=new Locale("zh", "cn");  
            }else if("english".equals(lan)){  
                locale=new Locale("en", "US");  
            }  
            return locale;  
        }  
    }
```

in `LocaleAction` :

```
public String execute(){  

        ActionContext ac=ActionContext.getContext();  
        ac.setLocale(getLocale());  
        return "success";  
    }
```

in jsp:

```
<a href="<s:property value="chinese"/>"><s:text name="china"></s:text></a>  
<a href="<s:property value="english"/>"><s:text name="us"></s:text></a>
```

Comment: it is good self explanatory but i have those as a files, so how to set that file corresponding to user selection